# How solve send mail issue

Tags: php, email, magento2, sendmail

І will try to send email but when i set the parameters for transportBuilder the page just reloads.

Through var_dump I learned that the page reloads before the sendMassage method.
For the sender and recipient fields, I tried to set the value simply through a string.

Locatiion of email_templates = Vendor/Module/etc/email_templates
Location of email template file = Vendor/Module/view/email/template.html

//Controller action

```php
$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
                $storeScope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('request_admin_email_answer_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                            'store' => Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                    ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_SENDER_EMAIL, $storeScope))
                    ->addTo($model->getEmail());
                $transport = $transport->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

//email_templates.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="request_admin_email_answer_template" label="Request price Answer" file="request_price_answer.html" type="text" module="Smile_Customer" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

//request_price_answer.html

```html
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Your Request: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}

{{trans "Answer for your request: %answer" answer=$data.answer_content}}
```

As a result, the email should go, but for now the page just reloads.

Comment: I get this error massage 
`    [2019-08-06 19:43:29] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Unable to send mail. 
Trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento_school/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Email\Model\Transport->sendMessage()
#1 /var/www/html/magento_school/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Email\Model\Transport\Interceptor->___callParent('sendMessage', Array) `

Comment: Is SMTP already set up? Maybe it's not sending because the mail server is not yet configured within Magento 2.